# What to use for federated AAD for B2C issuerAssignedId?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

How to get issuerAssignedId for federated Azure Active Directory?
My setup is the following: I have my application specific B2C and I have an active directory federated to my B2C using OpenID Connect. For metadata I'm using the following endpoint:
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration)

This working fine when users are sign up by themselves. However, for my particular business flow I can't let them do that. I need to pre-seed this users from the app itself. For this purpose, I have written a Microsfot Graph wrapper and trying to create users from this external directory. I'm trying to create a user with the following parameters:

```
POST /v1.0/users/ HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer my_token_received_using_client_credentials
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 263

{
  "displayName": "John Smith",
  "identities": [
    {
      "signInType": "federated",
      "issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0",
      "issuerAssignedId": "{**my_user_id_from_federated_active_directory**}"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, for an issuerAssignedId I'm using a user id from my federated Active Directory. However, this code doesn't work because when I'm using a sign-in flow with redirect to jwt.ms, I have the following error:

> AADB2C99002: User does not exist. Please sign up before you can sign in.

What should I use for this field for my federated users?

P.S. I have no problem with local accounts but I can't use them for my application. I must use users from external AD.

Comment: Are you using client credential flow for Azure ad b2c? b2c does not yet support this flow.

Comment: Are you using custom policy or user flow? When I last did this, I used AAD User ObjectId in the issuerAssignedId to seed the accounts. You can examine a user who signed up to see its issuerAssignedId via Graph Api beta endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally I figured it out. Counter-party AAD returning some nonsense in "sub" field (probably dependent on internal policies or something) and you have to use "oid" field (which is essentially users' object ID from AAD).

Comment: I would like to know what worked for you. Did you use "oid" to provide value for "issuerAssignedId"?

Comment: yes, oid was exactly what I was looking for. it can be any part of the token, you can put "iss" in there. it won't make any sense but it should work.