# Create federated AD user in ADB2C with Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

We have an OpenID connect in identity providers to authenticate AD users in ADB2C domain on UI. We created ADB2C users with temp password using graph before. But now I need to create a federated user who will be able to sign in using AD credentials. We also removed sign-up flow and left only sign-in as we want only create users via graph. I have the following code:

```cs
var newUser = new User
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
    GivenName = user.FirstName,
    Surname = user.Surname,
    Mail = user.Email,
    MobilePhone = user.Telephone,
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
        Password = PasswordGenerator.GeneratePassword(16),
    },
    Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity> 
    {
        new ObjectIdentity
        {
            SignInType = "federated",
            Issuer = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<AD TENANT>/v2.0",
            IssuerAssignedId = "<USER'S OBJECT ID FROM AD>",
        }
    },
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "IsAdmin", user.IsAdmin },
    },
    CreationType = null
};

var res = await _graphClient.Users.PostAsync(newUser);
```

But when I clicked 'sign in with AD' on UI and entered AD user's credentials, I got the following error: `AADB2C99002: User does not exist. Please sign up before you can sign in.`

Comment: Most likely the `sub` claim is used to identify the user in B2C. This value is unique per application in Azure AD, so you can't know it in advance :\

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm not sure I understood you correctly but I found a 'sub' claim mentioning in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64705343/what-to-use-for-federated-aad-for-b2c-issuerassignedid. Can you please explain what's you meant?

Comment: Basically when you configure the identity provider in B2C, you specify the claim that will be used to identify the user. By default in OpenID Connect it is the "sub" (subject) claim. If possible, you could change it to use "oid" (object ID) claim instead. You can read about their differences here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-token-claims-reference#payload-claims

Comment: Perfect! It was 'sub' and now it seems to work after I changed it to 'oid'. Millions of thanks

Comment: Hi @LevKostychenko, you can post it as answer to remove this question from unresolved in case it is resolved now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically when you configure the identity provider in B2C, you specify the claim that will be used to identify the user. By default in OpenID Connect it is the "sub" (subject) claim. If possible, you could change it to use "oid" (object ID) claim instead. You can read about their differences here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-token-claims-reference#payload-claims.